# How can i use Oauth 1.a based security in My JAX-RS Application?

Tags: jax-rs

Currently i'm working on a application, where server is  identifying each client using a session id.I would like to know how to make secure rest webservice using Oauth 1.a.Can any one help me please...

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at how we use Facebook authentication in a JAX-RS web application ([www.s3auth.com](http://www.s3auth.com)): https://github.com/yegor256/s3auth/blob/master/s3auth-rest/src/main/java/com/s3auth/rest/FacebookRs.java. Every time you get an ID from an OAuth provider you convert it to some secret string and return it back to the user in your own header. When the user comes back to you with this header you will decrypt it and get user ID.